# Difficulty getting a mixed line a and point legend that specifies colour and shape in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So I have been struggling to get a correct legend onto this plot. My end goal is a legend that shows both line colours and point colours. I can get the lines in the legend working ok but was wondering how I also get points too (and includes the shape **and** colour of points)? Any work around or advice much appreciated!

```
Tempx<-c(20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)
Tempx<-rep(Tempx,2)


Temp<-rnorm(1000,28,2)
var1<-rnorm(1000,25,5)
Data<-data.frame(Temp,var1)

Temp<-rnorm(1000,28,2)
var1<-rnorm(1000,12,5) 
Data2<-data.frame(Temp,var1)

a1<-1.05*Tempx
a2<-0.5*Tempx
a1low<-0.95*Tempx
a1high<-1.15*Tempx
a2low<-0.4*Tempx
a2high<-0.6*Tempx


plot1<-ggplot(NULL, aes(Temp, var1)) + 
  geom_point(data = Data, colour="grey60", size=1.5, shape=1, show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = Data2, shape= 16, size=1, show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a1, colour="grey50"), size=1.75, show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a2, colour="black"), size=1.75, show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a1low), colour="grey50",size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a1high), colour="grey50",size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a2low), colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Tempx,y=a2high), colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("low", "high"), values=c('black','grey50')) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4), "cm")), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4), "cm")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -6)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = -6)),
        axis.text=element_text(size=13),
        text = element_text(size=14),
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, hjust=0),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.1,"cm"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Temperature", breaks = c(20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34), expand=c(0,0), limits=c(20,34))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Variable 1", expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 40)) +
  ggtitle("Title")

plot1
```

Comment: this code could be massively shortened... not only very repetitive in your theme elements, but also are those not really relevant to the question. I would recommend to rbind the data frames, define different groups and use the fantastic grouping features from ggplot.  Also, having looked at your plot, I would recommend having a look at `geom_ribbon()`

Comment: Another suggestion, if you are trying to model a linear regression or similar, then you should have a look at 'geom_smooth()', see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit messy but I think it does what you want it to. Sorry for the kooky colours, I just pulled some out from colorbrewer.

```
library(ggplot2)

Tempx<-c(20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34)
Tempx<-rep(Tempx,2)


Temp<-rnorm(1000,28,2)
var1<-rnorm(1000,25,5)
var2<-rnorm(1000,12,5) 

a1<-1.05*Tempx
a2<-0.5*Tempx
a1low<-0.95*Tempx
a1high<-1.15*Tempx
a2low<-0.4*Tempx
a2high<-0.6*Tempx


dat1 <- data.frame(Temp,  var1, var2)
dat2 <- data.frame(Tempx, a1, a2, a1low, a1high, a2low, a2high)


plot2 <- ggplot() +
geom_point(data=dat1,aes(x=Temp,y=var1, colour="var1", size=1.5)) +
geom_point(data=dat1,aes(x=Temp, y=var2, colour="var2", size=1)) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx, y=a1, colour="a1"), size=1.75) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx,y=a2, colour="a2"), size=1.75) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx,y=a1low, colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash")) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx,y=a1high, colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash")) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx,y=a2low, colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash")) +
geom_line(data=dat2,aes(x=Tempx,y=a2high, colour="black",size=1.25, linetype="longdash")) +
scale_color_manual("",
    breaks = c("var1", "var2", "a1", "a2", "a1low", "a1high", "a2low", "a2high"), 
    values=c("#762a83", "#af8dc3","#e7d4e8","#f7f7f7","#d9f0d3","#7fbf7b","#1b7837", "#000000")) +
scale_size(guide = "none")+
guides(size="none", linetype="none")+ #removes linetype and sizes from legend
theme_bw()
```

:)

Answer (score 5):

You can shorten the code considerably by transforming your data from wide to long format. Then you need only one call to `geom_point` and `geom_line` Below is an example. `dat1` and `dat2` contain the points and main lines, respectively. `dat1` is already in long format. We convert `dat2` to `dat2long`as well. I've put `dat3long` in a separate data frame, as we don't need to map these values to a legend-generating aesthetic. Thus, I've used a separate call to `geom_line` for these lines and I've hard-coded the colors.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create long data frame for point data
dat1 = bind_rows(list(a1=Data, a2=Data2), .id="Source")

# Create long data frames for lines data
dat2 = data.frame(Tempx, a1, a2)
dat3 = data.frame(Tempx, a1low, a1high, a2low, a2high)
dat2long = dat2 %>% gather(Source, value, -Tempx)
dat3long = dat3 %>% gather(Source, value, -Tempx)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dat1, aes(Temp, var1, shape=Source, colour=Source)) +
  geom_line(data=dat2long, aes(x=Tempx, y=value, colour=Source)) +
  geom_line(data=dat3long, aes(x=Tempx, y=value, group=Source), linetype=2, 
            colour=rep(c("red","blue"), each=2*length(Tempx))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If your goal is to plot confidence intervals, you can do this:

```
ggplot(data=dat1, aes(Temp, var1, shape=Source, fill=Source, colour=Source)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote it I upvoted it because it was very helpful but it didn't really answer the question about the legend so it may be that (but I think it is a really valuable and useful answer nonetheless so thankyou!)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment: 
Let's start with cleaning up your data frames:

```
Temp<-rnorm(1000,28,2)
Data1<-data.frame(Temp,var = rnorm(1000,25,5), group = rep ('a', 1000)) ##adding groups
Data2<-data.frame(Temp,var = rnorm(1000,12,5), group = rep ('b', 1000))

data = rbind(Data1, Data2 )
```

now cleaning your `ggplot` call

A suggestion:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Temp, var, color = group )) + 
geom_point(size=1.5, shape=1) + 
geom_smooth(method = 'lm') #(maybe this model is what you want anyways)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You were actually very close with the `scale_shape_manual` and `scale_colour_manual` calls. The missing ingredient was putting the shapes for the two sets of points into a mapping for `geom_point` they way you did for colour in `geom_line`:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot2 <- ggplot(mapping=aes(x=Temp, y=var1)) +

  geom_point(data=Data, mapping=aes(shape="high"), colour="grey50", size=1.5) +
  geom_point(data=Data2, mapping=aes(shape="low")) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values=c(1, 16),
    guide=guide_legend(
      title="Legend: Points",
      override.aes=list(
        colour=c("grey50", "black"),
        size=c(1.5, 1)
      )
    )
  ) +

  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a1, colour="high"), size=1.75) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a2, colour="low"), size=1.75) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("grey50", "black"), guide=guide_legend(title="Legend: Lines")) +

  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a1low), colour="grey50", size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a1high), colour="grey50", size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a2low), colour="black", size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Tempx, y=a2high), colour="black", size=1.25, linetype="longdash") +

  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line.x=element_line(colour="black"),
        axis.line.y=element_line(colour="black"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(margin=unit(c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), "cm")), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(margin=unit(c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), "cm")),
        axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=-6)),
        axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(t=-6)),
        axis.text=element_text(size=13),
        text=element_text(size=14),
        plot.title=element_text(size=16, hjust=0),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1,"cm"),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Temperature", breaks=c(20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34), expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(20, 34)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Variable 1", expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 40)) +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

The code above gives a plot with two separate legends, one for points and one for lines:

[image: A plot with two separate legends, one for points and one for lines.]